# Address Subdivision

Tags: mips, offset

[image]

How can i decide the number of bits in each fields? 
I mean why 4 bits for offset?
I know how can i decide the number of bits in the index field .. because we have 64 blocks in cache (2^6), So the number of bits for index is 6.
And i know that the tag field is (32 - (index bits + offset bits) )
But the problem with the offset how can i know the number of bits needed for the offset field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 16 bytes per block you need 4 bits to determine which byte in that block is used.

Comment: Ooh Thanks !! I didn't notice that, the last question for you .. why we ignore 4 bits and we consider them as offset ?

Comment: @ReemAljunaid What do you mean ignore?

Comment: we always put the number of bits that we don't need in the offset, that what the offset represent, i mean why we ignore these 4 bits here? why they are not important ? why they are in the offset ?

Comment: @ReemAljunaid They are important. Otherwise you couldn't access that specific memory location. But the address is divided into several parts and they have different bits of the address, like the graphic shows. You need all parts to point to the specific location.